# Using onclick to call a function, which takes argument from an async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

So I am using POST to get data, in this case the variable lotSize, from a server side script.  I also have a function called doSomething, which takes lotSize as an argument.  However, I want doSomething to execute only when I click a button.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  Can anyone help?

```
def doSomething(sqFootage){
    //stuff to do
}

//this post sends address information to a server side script, 
//which returns the variable lotSize
$.post( 
     "/demo.php",
     { 
       pAddress: streetAddress,
       pCity: city,
       pState: state,
       pZip: zipCode     
     },
     function(lotSize) {
        event.preventDefault();

            //I want this function to only execute on a certain onclick
            doSomething(lotSize);

         });
```

Comment: Just put the AJAX call inside of the click handler?  I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: Initially disable the 'Do Something' button. When ajax call finishes (and you have the lotSize) then enable that button.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you want to do?

```
$('#IdOfYourButton').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post( 
     "/demo.php",
     { 
       pAddress: streetAddress,
       pCity: city,
       pState: state,
       pZip: zipCode     
     },
     function(lotSize) {
        event.preventDefault();
        doSomething(lotSize);

     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See step 1 to 3

```
// step 1) Put a global variable here, let's call it x
def doSomething(sqFootage){
//stuff to do
}

//this post sends address information to a server side script, 
//which returns the variable lotSize
$.post( 
 "/demo.php",
 { 
   pAddress: streetAddress,
   pCity: city,
   pState: state,
   pZip: zipCode     
 },
 function(lotSize) {
    event.preventDefault();

        //I want this function to only execute on a certain onclick
        //doSomething(lotSize);
        // step 2) Assign lotSize to the global variable x from step 1

     });

// step 3) Create the onclick event handler here and call doSomething(x); where x is the global variable that contains the value from lotSize
```